# The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

i have this query in my code I am getting this Error.

```
 var auditMandate = (from ae in genDB.AuditEvent
                     join at in genDB.AuditTable on // snip
                     select ae)
                     .OrderByDescending(x => 
                         x.DateTime_Updated).Take(500)
                     .Distinct().ToList();
```

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.  The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

is that something I am doing wrong this Linq?

Thanks

Comment: The xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Comment: I think your problem is that the xml data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to call DISTINCT on a collection of types that are not comparable, you know... the xml data type.

Comment: Its doable, you just have to work around it. See my answer. Performance is another issue and I didn't take into consideration the Take(500) but you'll get the point :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable. Take the query you have but get rid of the Distinct call. You still want a concrete list however so keep ToList(). Then follow this idea (since I don't know your xml structure):

My Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XmlTable](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [data] [xml] NULL
)
```

My Data

```
insert into XmlTable
values('<list id=''a''><items></items></list>')
insert into XmlTable
values('<list id=''b''><items></items></list>')
insert into XmlTable
values('<list id=''a''><items></items></list>')
```

My Comparer

```
    public class MyXDocumentCoparer : IEqualityComparer<XDocument>
    {
        public bool Equals(XDocument x, XDocument y)
        {
            var xId = x.Root.Attribute("id").Value;
            var yId = y.Root.Attribute("id").Value;
            return xId == yId;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(XDocument obj)
        {
            var id = obj.Root.Attribute("id").Value;
            return id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

My Code

```
    using (var ctx = new xmltestEntities())
    {
        // this would be your concrete list
        var rawData = ctx.XmlTables.ToArray();

        var processedData = rawData
            .Select(row => XDocument.Parse(row.data))
            .Distinct(new MyXDocumentCoparer());

        // you'll only get two, boom!
        foreach (var item in processedData)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Root.Attribute("id"));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to select distinct AuditEvents, but your LINQ provider doesn't know how to determine whether two AuditEvents are the same. Consider projecting into a class that knows how to do this comparison. Another option would be to use a GroupBy to produce items that are distinct based on specific properties:

```
.GroupBy(ae => ae.Id).Select(g => g.First());
```

As a side note, it generally makes more sense to do the distinct check before you call `Take`, so you'll still get up to 500 items even if the first 500 items in the original set contain duplicates.